# Trying to use passport with NodeJS and angular, but my code won't move past this point

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, sequelize.js, passport.js

I was following a tutorial and tried to make log in using passport but in my code. But while trying to log in, my form, that is my UI on press of the button doesn't do anything, it does not get redirected to my home page, it just stays as it is. I'll be posting code from front to back in that order. Passport config is where I get my problem currently, I tried everything, I am out of ideas, something isn't right and I didn't find much on the net, as there is no actual error, but if it worked, it would redirect me to home page, as I put in ts file. By the way I only added thing related to passport and this code, removed thing that are not related.

login.component.ts file ->

```
  signupForm!: FormGroup;
  constructor(private router:Router, private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
      'email': new FormControl(null,[Validators.required]),
      // 'email': new FormControl(null,[Validators.required,Validators.email]),
      'password': new FormControl(null,Validators.required)
    })
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.userService.login(JSON.stringify(this.signupForm.value)).subscribe(data=>{console.log('Success');this.router.navigate(['/home']);}, error=>console.log(error))
   }
```

Service in front ->

```
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrlL,body,{
      observe:'body',
      withCredentials:true,
      headers:new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type','application/json')
    });
  }
```

Model in front ->

```
export class UserModel {
  public id!: number;
  public ime!: string;
  public prezime!: string;
  public email!: string;
  public password!: string;
  
  constructor() {}
}
```

Passport-config - Here code won't go past `findOne()` method in the function. I posted `console.log()` near the end of the function, but it never gets called, neither does the rest of if case. The only message I get is in the console saying `` (sequelize) Warning: Model attributes (email) passed into finder method options of model korisnik, but the  options.where object is empty. Did you forget to use options.where? Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `ime`, `prezime`, `email`, `sifra` AS `password` FROM `korisnik` AS `korisnik` LIMIT 1; ``
Even when I add where clause, `Select` message gets shown and that's it.

Passport-config in the back ->

```
var passport = require("passport"),
  LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const UserCont = require("../controller/user-cont");
var User = require("../model/user_data");

passport.use(
  "local",
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password",
    },
    function (username, password, done) {
      User.User.findOne({ email: username }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err, { message: "testcase." });
        }
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect username." });
        }
        if (!UserCont.isValid(user.email, password)) {
          return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password." });
        }
        console.log("passport user", username);
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

login.js in the back ->

```
var User = require("../model/user_data");
var passport = require("passport");

module.exports.loginUser = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(501).json(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(501).json(info);
    }
    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(501).json(err);
      }
      return res.status(200).json({ message: "Login Success" });
    });
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

User-controller in the back ->

```
module.exports.isValid = (email, newPass) => {
  const salt = crypto.genSalt(10);
  const hashPass = crypto.hash(newPass, salt);
  User.User.findOne({ email: email }).then((user) => {
    crypto.compare(user.password, hashPass, function (err, ifValid) {
      if (ifValid == true) {
        console.log(ifValid);
        return true;
      }
    });
  });
};
```

User-routing file ->

```
const express = require("express");

const Login = require("../common/login");
const router = express.Router();
router.post("/login", Login.loginUser);
module.exports = router;
```

App.js (this also contains other things, i just put things related to passport) ->

```
//passport
var passport = require("passport");
var session = require("express-session");

app.use(
  session({
    name: "Session ID",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: "secret",
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 36000000,
      httpOnly: false,
      secure: false,
    },
  })
);
require("./common/passport-config");
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
//

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api", userRouting);
```

Model DB ->

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("./../common/db-config");
const Model = Sequelize.Model;

//User
class User extends Model {}

User.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      field: "id",
    },
    ime: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      field: "ime",
    },
    prezime: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      field: "prezime",
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      field: "email",
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      field: "sifra",
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "korisnik",
    tableName: "korisnik",
    timestamps: false,
  }
);

module.exports = { User };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `passport-config.js` file. You forgot to put where clause in User findOne. Try the following, hope this will help.

```
var passport = require("passport"),
    LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy,
    User = require("../model/user_data");

const UserCont = require("../controller/user-cont");

passport.use(
  "local",
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password",
    },
    function (username, password, done) {
       User.User.findOne({
         where: { email: username }
       }).then((user) => {
       if (!user) {
         return done(null, false, { message: `Username ${username} was not found.` });
        }
        user.comparePassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if (err) {
          return done(null, false, {message: err});
        }
        if (isMatch) {
          return done(null, user);
        } else if(!isMatch) {
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Your password is invalid.'});
        }
       });
     });
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Comment: I keep getting Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `ime`, `prezime`, `email`, `sifra` AS `password` FROM `korisnik` AS `korisnik` WHERE `korisnik`.`email` = 'milan@t-com.me'; and that's it, that's where it stops